# Convert Let-form to procedure form

Tags: scheme, procedure, let

I'm having trouble converting the following from let form to procedure

```
( let (( a 5)
b (* 5 2))
(let (b (* a b)
(c 10))
(+ b c)))
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't even compile, please fix it first

Answer (score 0):

A let expression is just syntactic sugar for lambda.

For example:

```
(let ((a 1)
      (b 2))
  (* a b))
```

is the same as

```
((lambda (a b) (* a b)) 1 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must fix it.

```
( let (( a 5)
(b (* 5 2)))
(let ((b (* a b))
(c 10))
(+ b c)))
```

definition of let is

```
(let (( variable-name1 value1)
 (variable-name2 value2)
 (variable-namen valuen))
 body)
```

convert to lambda is

```
((lambda (variable-name1 variable-name2 variable-namen) body) value1 value2 valuen)
```